# Getting WhiteLabel error page issue while running on localhost:8080 (Spring-boot web application)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a simple spring boot web application that will fetch all the details from a DB in my local and display it. But when I test it by running the application and opening localhost:8080/products uri, I am getting "Whitelabel Error Page" instead of list of products.

Also, if I don't give the "com.springweb.rest.repositories" as a basePackage in main class, it's not picking it up.

Can anyone tell me how to fix both these issues and why it's coming? Sharing my code and related config files.

This is my code:

**Main Springboot application class**

```
package com.springweb.rest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.springweb.rest.repositories")
public class ProductRestApiNewApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductRestApiNewApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Rest-Controller class**

```
package com.springweb.rest.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.springweb.rest.models.Product;
import com.springweb.rest.repositories.ProductRepository;

@RestController
public class ProductRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository repo;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/products",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Product> getAllProducts(){
        return repo.findAll();
    }

}
```

**Product Entity class**

```
package com.springweb.rest.models;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int price;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", description=" + description + ", price=" + price + "]";
    }
}
```

**Product repository class**

```
package com.springweb.rest.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.springweb.rest.models.Product;

public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Integer> {

}
```

**Application.properties file**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=********

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springweb.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>product-rest-api-new</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>product-rest-api-new</name>
    <description>Exploring Spring web and Spring boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hutN.png)

[This is the DB that I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfUVP.png)

Comment: Please try without this: `(scanBasePackages="com.springweb.rest.repositories")`. It is wrong. You can check JavaDoc for details.

Comment: Remove `scanBasePackages` and remove the `spring.autoconfigure.exclude`. YOu excluded the datasource configuration but want to use JPA. JPA without a datasource isn't going to work.

Comment: To debug this:

Check whether your controller is being scanned: Since you have specified scanBasePackages="com.springweb.rest.repositories" in your @SpringBootApplication annotation, Spring Boot is only scanning the repositories package for Spring Beans.

Comment: Did you try accessing url with extra / at the end?
localhost:8080/products/

Comment: If I remove that scanBasePackages I am getting issue from the Controller class above @Autowired annotation that there is not repository instance available. I am able to compile the code only if I give this scanBasePackages annotation.

Comment: if I remove spring.autoconfigure.exclude, I am getting the below exception:

"Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception with message: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/mydb"

Comment: I tried accessing the url in all the ways possible, it didn't seem to work  (With and without / in the end)

Comment: The jdbc url was wrong, So that's why I ended up adding the exclude-autoconfigure configuration, which resulted in the other errors and so on. 

Correcting the jdbc url fixed my issue. Hence closing it.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The jdbc connection url I used was wrong, So that's why I ended up adding the exclude-autoconfigure configuration, which resulted in the other errors and so on.
Correcting the jdbc url fixed my issue. Hence closing it.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: This is not an answer, you can leave a comment